# trying to post a json object via jquery ajax function ...to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm a bit new with JQuery / Ajax, I'm trying to post a JSON object via a JQuery ajax function ...the post is received by my PHP file, finder.php.
The code below works if I post a variable but if I try to post a JSON object I get the following error message,

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

here's my ajax function,

```
function swapContent(cv) {                              
    $("#myDiv").html('<img src="../../js/loader/bar_16x11.gif">').show();
    var url = "../../script/finder.php"

    $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data) { 
        $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

and here's the link sending the variable (or preferred json object) to the function

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent(\''.$json_obj.'\');">link name</a>';
```

how do i update it to accept a json object?

Comment: If you can help it, don't put your JSON object inline like that. It could very well have unescaped single quotes, opening you to both seemingly-random bugs and injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: You want your finder.php to echo only the json_obj itself (preferably json_encode()'d if you didn't do it yourself, and perhaps even a json header) and then the success function on the `$.post` should then build the rest of the html around it like  $("#myDiv").html("<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"return false\" onmousedown=\"javascript:swapContent('" + data.src + "');\">link name</a>").show();` assuming that the json_obj has a node called 'src'

Comment: Since you're putting json *in* HTML it should be html encoded.

Comment: sorry guys, not being much a javascript man, i didn't fully follow your answers. i sort of understood bits of what you mean, but not quite fully. sorry for asking you to hand hold but could you illustrate in detail what you mean?  ...where i php echo the link... echo '<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent(\''.$json_obj.'\');">link name</a>'; ...this is the initial link that sends the var or json object to the function, are you saying i should generate this link using jquery as opposed to php? that wouldn't be possible as the link is generated inside a php class

Answer (score 0):

earlier i said i'd resolved the issue by escaping characters in the json object that i carry over to the js function like this,

```
$json_obj = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($obj_array), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

but even better by encrypting the json string (at the starting php code), i don't have to escape the characters. gives the added benefit of no one guessing what values are passed to the js function, and i can be a little more liberal with what values i pass.. of course i'll escape the characters at the receiving php code